# Ordering of QMainWindows within a Qt Application

Tags: qt, qt4

I have an application where in the mainWindow(inherited from QMainWindow) creates a childWindow(also inherited from QMainWindow) and when run, both windows are launched with the childWindow masking the mainWindow.

In the mainWindow() constructor I have

```
setCentralWidget(this);
```

On Linux when the mainWindow->titleBar is clicked, the mainWindow is brought to the front whereas on Windows this doesn't seem to work.

To get a consistent behavior across platforms, I added a installEventFilter() and mouseEventHandler to account for left-button mouse events, but again none of methods I used within the mouse event handler helped me achieve the behavior I needed.

```
void mainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* mevent)
{
  if (Qt::LeftButton == mevent->button())
  {
    //this->raise();
    //this->show();
    //setCentralWidget(this);

  }
}
```

How can I switch to the mainWindow() when I press(mouse-event) the Title bar? 
Is there a reason why the behavior is different on Windows and Linux and how I do I make it consistent? I'm using the opensource versions of Qt-4.8.4 for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this function yet?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#stackUnder

and I would use this in tandem with `QFocusEvent`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusInEvent

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfocusevent.html#details